# Weird output from integer array to a file

Tags: c, system-calls

Hi I am writing a program that generates random ints, put them in an array and save them to  a file. Everything seems to work good but after I open this file it has this strange content : ^K^@^@^S^@^@^@^[^@
What have I done wrong?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int tab[10];
    int fd;
    srand(time(0));
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        tab[i] = rand() % 50;
    if(argc != 2 || strcmp(argv[1], "--help") == 0)
    {
        .......
    }
    fd = open(argv[1], O_RDWR | O_CREAT | O_TRUNC, 0644);
    write(fd, tab, 10);
    close(fd);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The content is wierd because you're writing *binary* values, random character codes from 0 to 50. But the information is there all right (well, you have to write `sizeof(int)` times more data to store all the data though, and it can be corrupt on Window because you're missing `O_BINARY` and some carriage return chars may be inserted at some locations...):

```
fd = open(argv[1], O_RDWR | O_CREAT | O_TRUNC, 0644); // add | O_BINARY if you use windows
write(fd, tab, 10 * sizeof(int));  // you can use (fd,tab,sizeof(tab)) too as it's an array, not a pointer
```

Use a hex editor you'll see the values (with a lot of zeroes since your values can be encoded in a byte). But not with a text editor.

If you want to write formatted integers as strings, use `fopen` and `fprintf` on the values, in a text file, not binary. Quick & dirty (and also untested :)):

```
FILE *f = fopen(argv[1], "w");  // #include <stdio.h> for this
if (f != NULL)
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
       fprintf(f,"%d ",tab[i]);
    }
    fclose(f);
}
```